# HAProxy with SSL and sticky sessions

Tags: ssl, haproxy, sticky-sessions, round-robin

We're trying to set up HAProxy (v1.5.1) to use SSL.

While we managed to do that, we're having some issues with the round robin settings:

We do want to have stick sessions, but haproxy seems to send all sessions (from different browsers) to the same node (`my.vm.2`), even though the other node (`my.vm.1`) is also available. So it looks like the round robin setting isn't working properly.

This is our current configuration, we would appreciate some help/ideas. :):

```
global
   debug
   stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin
   tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
   mode http
   balance roundrobin
   timeout connect 5s
   timeout queue   300s
   timeout client  300s
   timeout server  300s

frontend https_frontend
   bind *:8443
   mode tcp
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend my_backend


backend my_backend
   mode tcp
   stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
   stick on src
   default-server inter 1s
   server my.vm.1 my.vm.1:8443 check id 1 maxconn 500
   server my.vm.2 my.vm.2:8443 check id 2 maxconn 500
   option httpclose
   option redispatch
   retries 15

listen admin
   bind *:8081
   stats enable
   stats refresh 1s
```

Comment: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/05/configure-haproxy-to-load-balance-sites-with-ssl/ this might be of some use to you, but note my answer below.

Comment: @NathanC We tried this configuration, but it uses mode http instead of tcp so it didn't work. To my understanding, cookies won't work with tcp.

Comment: aha, you're right...

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest doing all your SSL processing in HAProxy and using the [proxy protocol](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) (`send-proxy` and `accept-sslproxy`) so client information gets passed from the ssl processor to the frontend+backend. That looks something like:

```
listen ssl-proxy
    bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mycert.pem npn http/1.1
    mode tcp
    bind-process 2 3 4
    server http 127.0.0.1:80 send-proxy

frontend dev
    #Do whatever you want here since it is http
    mode http
    bind 1.2.3.4:80 name dev
    bind 127.0.0.1:80 accept-proxy name accept-sslproxy
    bind-process 1

    acl is_ssl dst_port 443
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if is_ssl
    default_backend my_backend

backend my_backend
    mode http
    #Do whatever you want here since it is http
```

Comment: OK, so I tried this, but I now get a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Any ideas why this happens? Thanks

Comment: +1 mode TCP is an ill fit for session stickiness. - As for 502 errors, make sure to connect to a non-encrypted HTTP port on the backend server.

Comment: @FelixFrank Thanks for your comment, I tried connecting to non-encrypted tomcat servers, but now when I try to access secured pages (through haproxy) I get redirected to non-secured ones.

Comment: @Ayelet Tomcat should accept a certain Header to tell it about SSL being in use, even behind a proxy such as HAproxy. Make HAproxy add that header. If your application is generating the redirects, make sure that it honors the header as well.

Comment: @FelixFrank Do you maybe have an example/tutorial on how to add the header in haproxy? Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing, but I couldn't find something like that. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Ayelet: Updated my answer to include adding the X-Forwarded-Proto header

Comment: Nice :) If that doesn't help, you should open a new Question.

Comment: @KyleBrandt and Felix, thank you both for your comments. I actually found a very good tutorial that refers to Haproxy's new ssl capabilities.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 2):

Sticky sessions are IP-based, so different browsers will still go to the same backend because the source IP address remains the same.

Comment: Are the sticky sessions only based on IP, when SSL is being used? Or does that apply to both http and https?

Comment: @kasperd Both. You can however use session cookies instead with haproxy.

Comment: @NathanC But doesn't round robin means that every time we should go to a different node each time we refresh the page?

Comment: @Ayelet Yes and no. You're using sticky sessions so you'll always get sent to the same backend until the configured timeout. Round-robin attempts to do this (different server on refresh), but from what I understand it can be random depending on node load.